# makefile recursion all subsystems always up to date

Tags: recursion, makefile

I'm trying to create a recursive makefile but the make just reports all my subsystems are up to date when there are no object files, executables or even makefiles in the subdirectories.

```
    coco:
        if [ ! -f ./CoCo/makefile ]; then cp ./CoCo/Makefiles/Linux/makefile ./CoCo ;fi 
        $(MAKE) -C CoCo

    becker:
        if [ ! -f ./becker/makefile ]; then cp ./becker/Makefiles/Linux/makefile ./becker ;fi
        $(MAKE) -C becker
    ...
```

The first thing I would like to do in each subsystem is ensure the makefile exists and if it doesn't then copy it from the appropriate location.
Next I would like it to change to the subdirectory and perform the make.

Lastly how would I make all subsystems with one command like (make all)?

Comment: In case you tried `make becker` it probably reports "all up to date" because there is a directory with name `becker` and it exists and has no dependencies, so nothing to rebuild. As for `make coco` I don't know since the dir is apparently `CoCo` and case matters in linux... Does it work same for `make coco`?

Comment: What is "the appropriate location"?

Comment: The appropriate location is the source of the cp command.

Comment: @igagis Yes it does the same for CoCo.  I get the impression I need to explicitly perform the if with a shell!

Comment: @igagis You were correct.  Mingw on Windows is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `.PHONY: coco becker` to the beginning of your `makefile`, then it should run those targets even tough directories with same names exist